# Rails best practice - return AR query + arbitrary data to view via controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm wondering what the best practice is for passing a query + arbitrary data from a Rails controller to a view is?

```
# simple query
product = Product.find(id)
# some data to append to our instance var and send to view
extra_data = "some arbitrary string data"

@view = Hash.new
@view["product"]=product.attributes
@view["product"]["extra_data"]=extra_data
```

Is there a better / cleaner / shorter way? Maybe merging hashes?

Thanks!